# Sinon stub - Cannot destructure property 'x' of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: sinon, destructuring

I need to `stub` the following with [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) :

`const { clientId, dateString } = await parameterParser.prepareInputParameters(con, req);`

I have tried using the following:

```
const retData = {
        clientId: 872,
        dateString: '1970-01-01',
    };

sandbox.stub(parameterParser, 'prepareInputParameters').withArgs(con, req).returns(retData);
```

but I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'clientId' of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

I have successfully stubbed the following elsewhere in my tests:

```
const { retData } = await sqlFileReader.read('./src/database/sql/getClientIdFromLoanId.sql', [`${req.query.loan_id}`], con, req.logger);
```

by using:

```
const retData = {
        rowsCount: 1,
        rows: [{ client_id: 872 }],
    };
sandbox.stub(sqlFileReader, 'read').returns({ retData });
```

but I cannot get my head round how to stub `const { clientId, dateString }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `resolves` instead of `returns` for these stubs, since you are `awaiting` their return values, which should actually be [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolve with your `retData`, and not the `retData` itself.

In sinon, `resolves` is a convenience for asynchronous methods. The following two lines are similar:

```
sinon.stub(foo, 'bar').returns(Promise.resolve('baz'));
sinon.stub(foo, 'bar').resolves('baz');
```

Your second sample may not be throwing an error, but if you log the value of `retData` after this line:

```
const { retData } = await sqlFileReader.read('./src/database/sql/getClientIdFromLoanId.sql', [`${req.query.loan_id}`], con, req.logger);
```

You'll notice that it is `undefined`. This is because `await` causes the result of the method call to be a Promise, which does not have a property called `retData`.

As for why your first sample is behaving differently, I'm not sure. I suspect that there's something else going on that isn't evident from your samples. Would you mind sharing more code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't mind sharing more code but have no time till maybe Sunday to do so.  If I do get the chance I'll alert you here.